# copy class containing class to std::map

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, stdmap

I try to store the  instances of `Section` class in a std::map container. Each instance should be  accessible from multiple threads.  So the class must be both copyable and thread-safe. Below is my first approach and i need some explanation of behaving this code:

```
class SafePart{
  public:
    SafePart(){std::cout << "construct SafePart " << std::endl;};
   ~SafePart(){};
    SafePart(const SafePart &other){std::cout << "copy SafePart " << std::endl;};
    threadsafemethod(){std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); ...};
  private:

   // std::mutex mtx;
};

class Section {
  public:
    Section(){std::cout << "construct Section " << std::endl;};
   ~Section(){};
    somemethod(){sf.threadsafemethod();};
   // Section(const Section&){std::cout << "copy Section " << std::endl;};   
  private:
    SafePart sf;
};

int main() {
 std::map<int,Section> SecMap;  
 std::map<int,Section>::iterator it;
 Section s;
 SecMap.insert(std::make_pair(1,s));
 it=BoardMap.find(4);
 it->second.somemethod(); // is it still threadsafe?
 return 0;
}
```

**case1**:If I provide this copy constructor `Section(const Section&){std::cout<< "copy Section " <<std::endl;};` to `Section` class, the output is:

```
construct SafePart   
construct Section 
construct SafePart 
copy Section 
construct SafePart 
copy Section 

/*conlusion:constructor is called on SafePart, when Section is copied to std::Map*/
```

**Case2**:and when `Section` class has no copy constructor (leaving it for compiler) the output is:

```
construct SafePart 
construct Section 
copy SafePart 
copy SafePart 

/*conlusion:copy constructor is called on SafePart, when Section is copied to    std::Map*/
```

Each instance after storing(coping) in std::map container should be still threadsafe, so which case should i choose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your first code, is that your `Section` copy constructor doesn't tell the compiler which `SafePart` constructor to use, so the compiler just uses the default constructor.  You have to use the initializer list to tell the compiler which `SafePart` constructor to use.  In the second example without any copy constructor, the compiler makes one for you, and the default one copy constructs the members one by one, which is the correct behavior 99% of the time.

In general, avoid writing constructors, assignment operators, and destructors unless you *really* need them.  When do need them, use initializer lists in your constructors.

Here's Safepart where I've added the copy assignment and move operations.  The move operations don't help your particular code, but they're a good idea in general.  Also note I've marked all of these as `noexcept`.  Also not necessary, but a good idea.

```
class SafePart{
  public: 
     SafePart(){std::cout << "def ctor SafePart " << std::endl;};
     ~SafePart(){};
     SafePart(const SafePart &other) noexcept
     {std::cout << "cpy ctor SafePart " << std::endl;};
     SafePart&operator=(const SafePart &other) noexcept
     {std::cout << "cpy asn SafePart " << std::endl;return *this;};
     SafePart(SafePart &&other) noexcept
     {std::cout << "mov ctor SafePart " << std::endl;};
     SafePart&operator=(SafePart &&other) noexcept
     {std::cout << "mov asn SafePart " << std::endl;return *this;};
};
```

And here's how to handle members and parent classes.  The key parts are the initializer lists `:sf(other.sf)` and similar.  This gets the desired behavior.

```
class Section {
  public:
    Section (){std::cout << "def ctor SafePart " << std::endl;};
   ~Section (){std::cout << "dtor SafePart " << std::endl;};

    Section (const Section &other) noexcept 
    :sf(other.sf)
    {std::cout << "cpy ctor SafePart " << std::endl;};

    Section & operator=(const Section &other) noexcept
    {sf=other.sf; std::cout << "cpy asn SafePart " << std::endl;}; 

    Section (Section &&other) noexcept
    :sf(std::move(other.sf))
    {std::cout << "move ctor SafePart " << std::endl;};

    Section & operator=(const Section &&other) noexcept
    {sf=std::move(other.sf); std::cout << "mov asn SafePart " << std::endl;};

  private:
    SafePart sf;
};
```

And I tweaked your main to not do unnecessary copies, using `map::emplace` with `piecewise_construct` and two `forward_as_tuple` calls.  This causes it to skip a copy.

```
int main() {
 std::map<int,Section> SecMap;  
 std::map<int,Section>::iterator it;
 Section s;
 std::cout << "BREAKPOINT 1\n";
 SecMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,std::forward_as_tuple(1),std::forward_as_tuple(s));
 std::cout << "BREAKPOINT 2\n";
 return 0;
}
```

So now I get this output:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/219644edd8253da9

```
def ctor SafePart 
def ctor Section 
BREAKPOINT 1
cpy ctor SafePart 
cpy ctor Section 
BREAKPOINT 2
dtor Section 
dtor Section
```

Comment: thx yours response is very helpful. Can i ask what happens to `std::mutex` in `SafePart` class after this initialization:`Section (const Section &other) noexcept :sf(other.sf)` and cpy ctor SafePart is called? Is this mutex initialized properly and i can use it when i get object from std::map container?

Comment: constructors _always_ call constructors for all members (if they exist), so the `mutex` will be initialized.  However, `mutex`'s should not be copied or moved, so I don't know what you want your code to do to make it "right".  Right now it just makes a brand new mutex, which I guess is what you want?  Or maybe you want to use a `std::unique_ptr<mutex>` or `std::shared_ptr<mutex>`?

Comment: `Right now it just makes a brand new mutex, which I guess is what you want?` Yes, so far i want a new mutex(i am aware of that mutex's should not be copied or moved) for each instance(copy) inserted into std::map container.